# rails ajax to render form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a "join" button on my page that when clicked, the user `joins` the model. Similar to follow button. In my `join.js.erb` file, I'm rendering partials after a user has joined, like the partial to show the unjoin button as well as a form where they can now comment on the model. Here is how it looks.

```
*join.js.erb*

$("#restaurant-<%= @restaurant.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'restaurants/join_button', :locals => { :restaurant => @restaurant } %>");
$("#restaurantCommentForm").html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'restaurants/comments_form', :locals => { :restaurant => @restaurant } %>");
```

Here is the comment partial

```
<% if current_user.voted_on?(restaurant) %>
  <div class="section-wrapper section-wrapper-two">
    <h4 class="text-muted text-center" style="margin: 0 0 10px;">Write a review</h4>

    <%= render :partial => "comments/form", :locals => { :comment => @comment } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So the js file is rendering a partial, which is rendering another partial, both with locals.

The error I'm getting is where `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

```
ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):
  1: <%= form_for([@commentable, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

I assume this is an issue with my locals in the comment_partial. Does anyone know a proper solution for this??
Thanks

**I've tried this already** in the comments_form partial

```
<%= render :partial => "comments/form", :locals => { :restaurant => @commentable, :comment => @comment } %>
```

Comment: Where do you set the value of `@commentable` and `@comment`?

Comment: In the controller. `@commentable = @restaurant`, because the commentable model here is the restaurant model. `@comment = Comment.new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the chat session, `@comment` and `@commentable` instance variables were not set in action `join`. Hence, the error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

```
 def join
    begin
      @vote = current_user.vote_for(@restaurant = Restaurant.friendly.find(params[:id]))     
      @commentable = @restaurant ## Set the value
      @comment = Comment.new    ## Set the value
      respond_with @restaurant, :location => restaurant_path(@restaurant)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      redirect_to restaurant_path(@restaurant)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Same error with the form cannot contain nil or be empty